# How do I print the contents of a ruby variable in the view of my Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm quite a rails beginner, but I am trying to see the contents of a Ruby variable from within my Rails View (html.haml file).  I tried to print out the variable in ruby (thinking it would turn out in the terminal), but didn't get any results. Any suggestions?

I know about the Rails Debugger, but would rather prefer printing out my variables using inspect instead.

Comment: it depends on the variables passed to the view... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812341/rails-3-display-variable-from-controller-in-view if you add some code we might be able to help you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `puts` method from within your views to output information to your server console. You should be able to do the following using Haml from anywhere in your view:

```
- puts @my_variable.inspect
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
= debug @object
```

It's going to print and highlight the variable in the view.

Answer (score 0):

In case of requiring more detailed debug messages you could try something like this

view.haml

```
    = debug "my_variable_value: #{@my_variable}"
```

controller.rb

```
    def index
      @my_variable = true
    end
```